# Medical Device Interface Standards?

Tags: interface, medical

I tried to find some standards about medical x-ray device interfaces. I found some icon restrictions but that's all.  Is there any good resource and standards for Medical Device Interfaces that you can recommend / share?

Thanks,

Comment: As far as i know most of the medical world's software interfaces range somewhere between 'absolutely godawful' and 'really not that great' in every regard, including consistency and standards.
Most will be used to winforms-era microsoft standards so at the very least I'd be considerate of that. *(edit; 'considerate' meaning feel more so than looks; you don't have to make your interface a tiny battleship-gray 1990's throwback)

Answer (score 1):

There are not a lot of design standards.  The main one that applies is HE 75.  There is a draft available of the next version http://my.aami.org/aamiresources/previewfiles/HE75_1311_preview.pdf

Ed Israeli did a good summary of the standards that apply here, but most are process standards. http://www.hfes.org/web/HFESmeetings/HCSpresentations/israelskistandardsppt.pdf